# Nginx service not accessible via Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have created a `helm` chart for `redash` and deployed on GKE.

All my services are up and running.

The service that is created as `LoadBalancer` points to my `nginx`:

```
▶ k get svc nginx -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    helm.sh/created: "1574525412"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-11-23T16:10:12Z"
  labels:
    chart: nginx-1.0.0
    component: giddy-greyhound-nginx
    heritage: Tiller
    release: giddy-greyhound
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "584346"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nginx
  uid: bacf3b27-0e0b-11ea-9a24-42010aa40054
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.0.3.10
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    component: giddy-greyhound-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

From within the cluster, running `curl -L nginx` retrieves the expected web page.

I have also the following rule in my `Firewall Rules`:

[image: be]

However, when hitting the cluster endpoint, say `34.99.12.123` it times out (as if it were blocked by firewall)

and when hitting the LoadBalancer's IP (say `76.33.21.123`) it immediately gives me that the site cannot be reached (refused to connect).

Any suggestions about how to further debug what might be wrong with my configuration?

Shouldn't I be able to access my web page from both the GKE Cluster endpoint as also the LB's IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your configuration we can clearly see that your service is of type: ClusterIP.

This means that you have an error in the configuration and you should try modifying the service type to LoadBalancer.

For a more precise debug you could generate a yaml from your chart and post-it in your post.

From what you said and the configuration you posted I can't understand how the loadbalancer was created.